# SSRS Chart, is there a way to left-align the y-axis?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have a bar chart and I would like the text to be left-aligned.  I've tried checking the Vertical Axis Properties and there are Label and Label Font settings, but alignment is not one of the settings.

**What I've tried:**

I have tried to use the alignment icons on the toolbar, but they are grayed out.  I've also tried right-clicking on the chart, choosing Chart > Layout, and all of the alignment options are grayed out there as well.

What is the best method to align the labels to the left, while keeping the gradient bars looking the same please?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is possible using a chart.

What you can do instead is to create a table with two columns, grouped on the same field as your chart Category.  In the first column you can simply put the Category label and in the second column add a chart, you can use a [data bar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/sparklines-and-data-bars-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017).

This will allow you to format your 'labels' and chart bars as you see fit.